# Accessing Kinect Accelerometer

Tags: kinect, accelerometer

I want to access Kinect accelerometer to determine whether the device carrier is moving or not. Is it possible with Kinect accelerometer? If it so, how can i do that? is ofxKinect framework useful for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The microsoft SDK contains a method to read the accelerometer: [KinectSensor.AccelerometerGetCurrentReading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinectsensor.accelerometergetcurrentreading.aspx)

```
private void OnAllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
   if (this.KinectSensor == null)
   {
      return;
   }

   Vector4 reading = this.KinectSensor.AccelerometerGetCurrentReading();
}
```

[ofxKinect](https://github.com/ofTheo/ofxKinect/blob/master/src/ofxKinect.h) has a few methods that sound promising:

```
/// get the XYZ accelerometer values
///
/// ... yes, the kinect has an accelerometer

/// raw axis values
ofPoint getRawAccel();

/// axis-based gravity adjusted accelerometer values
///
/// from libfreeenect:
///
/// as laid out via the accelerometer data sheet, which is available at
///
/// http://www.kionix.com/Product%20Sheets/KXSD9%20Product%20Brief.pdf
///
ofPoint getMksAccel();

/// get the current pitch (x axis) & roll (z axis) of the kinect in degrees
///
/// useful to correct the 3d scene based on the camera inclination
///
float getAccelPitch();
float getAccelRoll();
```